# Does anybody know how to derive the Bolzman equation for photon distribution function in the presence of tensor perturbations?

Tags: cosmology

Does anybody know of how to derive the Bolzman equation for photon distribution function in the presence of tensor perturbations? Ok, this is actually a problem (4.13) in Dodelson's book. I got stuck at some point and do not know how to figure it out. Do anybody know of some books or references which may solve this?
Really thank you for your help.